# How to add a library to my project in a visual studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I needed to use [zydis](https://github.com/zyantific/zydis) library in my VC2019 cpp project.
I have no idea how can I add it to my current project - I downloaded it from github.

There is msvc folder, inside I can find .sln file, some header files and .vcxproj files - what should I do, to just include it into my project and use it?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by adding a reference to the DLL file.
In Visual Studio, right click on the project, Add Reference. Give the path to the DLL file and add it to the project.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest that you could download and install Zydis using the vcpkg dependency manager. The method is easy and convenient.

If you don't use vcpkg, you could follow the steps below.

1. Open the Zydis.sln in `msvc` with VS2019.
2. Copy files in [include/Zycore](https://github.com/zyantific/zycore-c/tree/4793880c560f3e11f8d1093ffc407e377fcce20c), put them in `zydis-master\include\Zycore`. Because I find that there should be missing files when I compile `Zydis.sln`.
3. Right click `Zydis`, set `Visual Studio 2019(v142)` in `Properties->General->Platform Toolset`.
4. Compile it, and you will find `Zydis.lib` in `zydis-master\msvc\bin\DebugX64`.

Then, you could copy `include` floder and lib in your program floder.

You could set VS:

> 1. Right-click the project, select Properties->Configuration
>    Properties->C/C++->General, find the `Additional Include Directories` and set the directory.
> 2. Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker ->
>    General, find the `Additional library directory` in General, and set the lib.
> 3. Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input,
>    find `Additional Dependencies` and input the lib name.

Besides, you could set [five build configurations](https://github.com/zyantific/zydis/tree/master/msvc).